# clGetPlatformIDs failed: <unknown error -1001>

Tags: python, opencl, ubuntu-16.04, nvidia, pyopencl

when i run following code

```
import pyopencl as cl
cl.get_platforms()
```

I get error

```
clGetPlatformIDs failed: <unknown error -1001>
```

I am running python 3.6 pyopencl 2018.1.1 on aws ec2 Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-116-generic x86_64).

I have tried following things , but none of them work:

1. `echo libnvidia-opencl.so.1 >> /etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd`
   from root directory by doing `sudo -i`
   after ssh into ubuntu ec2 instance. (initially this command wont work so i removed nvidia.icd file `{rm nvidia.icd}`and then this command worked. but it did not solve the error 1001 mentioned above.
2. `echo libnvidia-opencl.so.384.111 >> /etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd`
3. `sudo ln -s /opt/intel/opencl-1.2-3.2.1.16712/etc/intel64.icd /etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd`
4. `sudo usermod -aG video your-user-name`
5. `sudo ln -s /usr/share/nvidia-331/nvidia.icd /etc/OpenCL/vendors`
6. `sudo ln -s /usr/share/nvidia-384/nvidia.icd /etc/OpenCL/vendors`
7. `optirun myopenclprogram`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to use OpenCL on EC2 is by using the Deep Learning Base Image, which comes with all necessary drivers and is already configured to work with P2 and P3 instance types. The image can be found at https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B077GCH38C.

Comment: yes +1. instead of updating ubuntu its best to use new image with preinstalled ubuntu 16. Then installing pyopencl with conda solves it.